# PhpStorm open floating directory tree

Tags: phpstorm

How can I open the floating directory tree on a Mac using PhpStorm 2016.2.1

Like this:

[image: floating directory]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a **Navigation Bar** on your screenshot.

As far as I'm aware: in order to see that bar *floating* it has to be *hidden* in GUI. For that: make sure that `View | Navigation Bar` is inactive/un-checked.

With the above condition in place, the shortcut for `Navigate | Jump to Navigation Bar` (<kbd>Alt + Home</kbd> on Windows using Default keymap) will bring that bar floating. Otherwise (with Navigation Bar permanently visible) that action/shortcut should just focus existing Navigation Bar.

Answer (score 1):

"cmd+up" is what you're looking for I believe.

Comment: Then you probably mapped it to another key. You can go to "Preferences > Keymap" and search for "Jump to Navigation Bar" to see what key it's mapped to.